# Redirecting unauthorized users to another controller action

Tags: yii2

I have this controller code for login:

```
 public function actionLogin()
        {
            if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
                return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/telephone/index'); 
            }

            $model = new LoginForm();
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
                return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/telephone/index'); 
            }
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
```

And for preventing the `add` and `delete` action for unauthorized users i used:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
            'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['add','delete'],
            'rules' => [
                // allow authenticated users
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                // everything else is denied by default
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

But if unauthorized users clik add or delete, it is redirected to `site/login`. How can i change that controller and action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different approaches to changing that route depending on the scope. They all involve changing the [`loginUrl`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#$loginUrl-detail) property of the [`yii\web\User`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html) class.

**Global**

Edit config file.

```
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'loginUrl' => ["controller/action"],  
    ],
],
```

**Controller/Action**

Edit beforeAction method of the controller.

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    // action-specific
    if(in_array($action->id,['not', 'allowed', 'actions']))
        Yii::$app->user->loginUrl = ["controller/action"];

    // controller-wide
    Yii::$app->user->loginUrl = ["controller/action"];

    if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: either way it is not working. still redirecting to site/login

Comment: also taking into account the other answer, have you configured accessrules for sitecontroller as well?

Comment: or maybe invalid route. try setting the `loginUrl` property to `null` in the config. this should give you a `403 exception` upon access denycallback.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['add','delete'],
            'rules' => [
                'allow' => true,
                'actions' => ['add','delete'],
                'roles' => ['@'],
                'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                    return $this->redirect('index.php?r=site/login');
                }
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: still redirecting to site/loigin even when i change the url in matchcallback.